# Show message box in case of exception

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I'm wondering what the correct way is to pass on an exception from one method to my form.

```
public void test()
{
    try
    {
        int num = int.Parse("gagw");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Form:

```
try
{
    test();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

in this way i cannot see my text box.

Comment: try/catch in `test` method is redundant.

Comment: The `exceptions` bubble up the call chain.

Comment: I don't see any problem here. messagebox should popup. What's happening?

Comment: You should be able to see message box. What happens if you replace try-test-catch-messagebox with just `MessageBox.Show("Hi")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347531/using-messagebox-to-show-exception-information-in-multithreaded-application

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want just the summary of the exception use:

```
    try
    {
        test();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

If you want to see the whole stack trace (usually better for debugging) use:

```
    try
    {
        test();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

---

Another method I sometime use is:

```
    private DoSomthing(int arg1, int arg2, out string errorMessage)
    {
         int result ;
        errorMessage = String.Empty;
        try 
        {           
            //do stuff
            int result = 42;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            errorMessage = ex.Message;//OR ex.ToString(); OR Free text OR an custom object
            result = -1;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And In your form you will have something like:

```
    string ErrorMessage;
    int result = DoSomthing(1, 2, out ErrorMessage);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ErrorMessage);
    }
```

Comment: There is no need to change the original OP's code, because original code should work. The problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @Dialecticus the questions was about `the correct way`. The above were mere suggestions.

Comment: All I'm saying is you are trying to solve a non-existing problem. Or worse, you are giving an answer to non-existing question.

Comment: I believe the user's problem is the message box occludes the text box. "in this way I cannot see my text box" and no one has answered this (much more complex} issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, for example:

Method one:

```
public string test()
{
string ErrMsg = string.Empty;
 try
    {
        int num = int.Parse("gagw");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrMsg = ex.Message;
    }
return ErrMsg
}
```

Method two:

```
public void test(ref string ErrMsg )
{

    ErrMsg = string.Empty;
     try
        {
            int num = int.Parse("gagw");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrMsg = ex.Message;
        }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to change the original OP's code, because original code should work. The problem lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
        try
        {
           // your code
        }
        catch (Exception w)
        {
            MessageDialog msgDialog = new MessageDialog(w.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the op and further visitor, when you add some eplaination to your intension (Use the edit link underneath your post for doing that).