# Fill data to combobox from sql command

Tags: c#

I'm using below code but, it's giving me an error.

```
private void ma2()
{
    try
    {  
        string query = "select  k7 from kholy1";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader drd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (drd.Read())
            {
            comboBox5.Items.Add(drd.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
        drd.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error ");
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error while displaying the form!

Comment: Could you please properly format the question? Then Include the error message as well to get better solutions from our site

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: display        MessageBox.Show("Error ");

Comment: Update your `catch` to `catch (Exceptione)` and the do `MessageBox.Show(e.Message);` to get the actual error message. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823668/show-message-box-in-case-of-exception

Comment: Error is the message on catch phrase but was is the actual error? Also what part in your code is `con`? We can only see `con.open()` but no `SqlConnection` etc etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just simply use combo box tasks and check use Data Bound Items that's how you are able to connect it to sql database. Value member use to store it's value in database and Display Member use to Display value in front end.

You can use selected value using **combobox1.SelectedValue**.

Reference- [Binding WPF ComboBox to a Custom List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561166/binding-wpf-combobox-to-a-custom-list)[image]

Comment: How do you know, he is using WPF? What if he's not using the UI editor?

Comment: OP never stated he was using WPF and asking in code form.